# PicketLink/JSF Error SecurityConfigurationException

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jboss-weld

I have just started working on Picketlink for my JSF application. I copied the code from  [this source](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/tree/master/picketlink-authentication-idm-jsf).

I had to make a few changes, such as removing the Singleton and Startup Annotations from the IDMInitializer because I use Tomcat.

The code in the quick start link above won't compile as is against Picketlink 2.5 beta 5 so I had to make quite a few changes that I am not sure if is correct. Below is the code and exception. I would appreciate any pointers especially if any one has a link to a working example with JSF (on Tomcat)

**Exception:**

```
<pre><code>
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.picketlink.authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.picketlink.authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
at org.picketlink.internal.DefaultIdentity.authenticate(DefaultIdentity.java:204)
at org.picketlink.internal.DefaultIdentity.login(DefaultIdentity.java:110)
at org.picketlink.internal.DefaultIdentity$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.login(Unknown Source)
at picketlinkDemo.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 27 more
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.config.SecurityConfigurationException: To use JPAIdentityStore you must provide an EntityManager producer method qualified with @org.picketlink.annotations.PicketLink.
at org.picketlink.internal.EEJPAContextInitializer.initContextForStore(EEJPAContextInitializer.java:26)
at org.picketlink.idm.internal.DefaultStoreFactory.getStoreForFeature(DefaultStoreFactory.java:213)
at org.picketlink.idm.internal.DefaultStoreFactory.getStoreForFeature(DefaultStoreFactory.java:187)
at org.picketlink.idm.internal.DefaultIdentityManager.validateCredentials(DefaultIdentityManager.java:384)
at org.picketlink.internal.SecuredIdentityManager.validateCredentials(SecuredIdentityManager.java:171)
at org.picketlink.authentication.internal.IdmAuthenticator.authenticate(IdmAuthenticator.java:47)
at org.picketlink.internal.DefaultIdentity.authenticate(DefaultIdentity.java:187)
... 40 more

</pre></code>
```

**My code:**

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
    package picketlinkDemo;


import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.picketlink.Identity;
import org.picketlink.Identity.AuthenticationResult;
import org.picketlink.idm.IdentityManager;
import org.picketlink.idm.config.FileIdentityStoreConfiguration;
import org.picketlink.idm.config.FileStoreConfigurationBuilder;
import org.picketlink.idm.config.IdentityConfiguration;
import org.picketlink.idm.config.IdentityConfigurationBuilder;
import org.picketlink.idm.config.IdentityStoresConfigurationBuilder;


import org.picketlink.idm.credential.Password;
import org.picketlink.idm.file.internal.FileDataSource;
import org.picketlink.idm.internal.IdentityManagerFactory;
import org.picketlink.idm.model.Realm;
import org.picketlink.idm.model.SimpleUser;
import org.picketlink.idm.model.User;


@Named
public class LoginController {


    //@Inject
    //private IdentityManager identityManager;
    @Inject
    private Identity identity;
    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;
   IdentityConfigurationBuilder builder = new IdentityConfigurationBuilder();
    FileIdentityStoreConfiguration configuration;
    //IDMInitializer initMethod = new IDMInitializer ();
    public void login() {
       builder.stores().file().preserveState(false).addRealm(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM, "Testing").addTier("Application")
                .supportAllFeatures();


        IdentityStoresConfigurationBuilder store = new IdentityStoresConfigurationBuilder(builder);
        FileStoreConfigurationBuilder fileStore = store.file();
        configuration = fileStore.create();
//Config is an instance of FileIdentityStoreConfiguration
        IdentityConfiguration configuration = builder.build();
        IdentityManagerFactory identityManagerFactory = new IdentityManagerFactory(configuration);
       IdentityManager identityManager = identityManagerFactory.createIdentityManager();
        User user = new SimpleUser("jane");


        user.setEmail("jane@doe.com");
        user.setFirstName("Jane");
        user.setLastName("Doe");


        identityManager.add(user);
        identityManager.updateCredential(user, new Password("abcd1234"));


        AuthenticationResult result = identity.login();
        if (AuthenticationResult.FAILED.equals(result)) {
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    "Authentication was unsuccessful.  Please check your username and password " + "before trying again."));
        }
    }
}
</pre></code>